# Unknown Filesystem : cannot create new file system

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted, format

So I have this internal HDD. One day I was installing something and after that I wasn't able to move or copy stuff from the drive. I have a SSD and a HDD inside my lap. The problem was with my HDD(1 TB). And I have 2 partitions one of 350 gigs and and rest in 750. The 750 was not accessible after this incident. So I try to format it and still I'm not able to use it.

So now I remove my HDD from my laptop and plug it into my other laptop which has a Linux system in it . And when I check in Gpart the file system is showing as unknown with an exclamation on its side.

So I delete the partion and it is successful.
Next I created a partition table of MsDOS.
and then i created a new partition of type NTFS of full size. 
and then the error occurs.
[image: Error while partitioning]

Im a total noob here. please help.
Thank you.

Comment: read this https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Comment: So i did the test disk as the website said but a new error came : `Disk /dev/sdb - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63                                                                   Analyse cylinder    20/121600: 00%                                                                                      Read error at 19/254/63 (lba=321299)                                                                                                                                                                                                              HPFS - NTFS      0  32 33 121601  57 56 1953521664`

Comment: Although not an answer to your question , but if you don't want to use that partition in windows (easily) , you can also format it as a more-linux-compatible filesystem like ext4 . NTFS support is limited in linux because of the proprietary nature of that.

Comment: Although not an answer to your question , but if you don't want to use that partition in windows (easily) , you can also format it as a more-linux-compatible filesystem like ext4 . NTFS support is limited in linux because of the proprietary nature of that.

Comment: open disk by typing "disks" in menu and run smart data and self test. There you also get options for disk bench marking and disk image restore.